# Storing dictionaries in a database

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, crud

I am trying to build a CRUD app where there is a user and admin side in the website. Where the admins can create a quiz that the users can view on their side of the page. The admin can choose to create a quiz and can keep adding as many questions as they like with the click of an "Add New Question button". When they finish making the quiz, they would select create quiz and it would be now displayed on the user side. My question is, how should I store the questions and answers to the quiz in the database since the admin can specify as many questions as they like. Some people have told me to store it as a dictionary in the database with question number as the key and the question name and 4 different answers as the values, how do I do that or is there any other better way to do this?

[image]

Comment: The values I would like to store would be, the quiz name, each question name, the content of the 4 answers in each queston, the number of questions and which is the correct answer(radio button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two tables. One for question and one for answers:

```
tbl_question
id | description

tbl_answer
id | question_id | description | is_correct
```

Then do

```
SELECT q.*, a.description, a.is_correct
FROM tbl_question q
JOIN tbl_answer a ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE q.id = :questionId
```

to select question with it's all answers.

*Add any additional information to tables as needed*

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer Justin, but currently in my database all I see is the tbl_answer table, the tbl_question table does not appear in the database, I am using MySql. Also where would I insert this statement, there seems to be an error in the syntax for this statement

"SELECT q.*, a.description, a.is_correct
FROM tbl_question q
JOIN tbl_answer a ON a.question_id = q.id
WHERE q.id = :questionId"

Comment: I am sorry if I come off as slightly blur, I have been doing JavaScript for only 6 months now in school and just got exposed to databases.

Comment: You might want to return the answers in a random order. Take a look at [This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56653771/how-to-select-data-from-mysql-with-limit-contains-one-element-with-value-eg-1)

Comment: @ArmanKhan So if you have missing table, create one. And there is prepared statement for your PHP side, not full MySql query.