# How to Select data from MYSQL with LIMIT contains one element with value eg. 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got table with list's of answer's for some test questions. Every test got only one answer true. How to select from mysql with limit to eg 3 answers with one correct. Answers are random

```
SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE correct='true' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3
```

Comment: You could run 2 separate queries.

Comment: something  like this: 
SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE correct='true' && idquestion='1'; SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE idquestion='1' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3

Comment: @Prokul [This demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4083a5bac905becde393f8eb4a04f8d6) will return the Correct answer as the first one and the remaining two options in the random order. It is not the exact answer, but may helpful in some way.

Comment: @Arulkumar thx, very close, but i need random answers with correct too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `UNION ALL` and sub query will help to get your expected result.

The following query will help in your case:

```
SELECT Answer FROM (
    SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT Answer, 1 AS ManualOrder FROM Answers WHERE Correct = 'true' AND QId = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT Answer, RAND() FROM Answers WHERE Correct != 'true' AND QId = 1 
    ) AS Q 
    ORDER BY ManualOrder DESC LIMIT 3
) W ORDER BY RAND()
```

Please find [**demo on db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=62ccf60ad3c2b460ebf0b3511438c8c0)

In my demo, `Answer 04` is the correct answer for the question id `1`, in the result set, `Answer 04` is always return along with 2 other answers in the random order.

Comment: Other than your saying Answer 04 is the correct answer, how can we tell by what's being returned? Shouldn't column `Correct` also be returned? Excellent!

Comment: @Arulkumar That's it! Work's great. Thanks ;)